# Is it possible to solve encoding problems?

Tags: accents, characters, input-encodings

I have some tex files that are corrupted, meaning that characters like accented letters have been replaced with weird symbols. Is it possible to solve this kind of problem after the weird symbols appear, or is it already too late?

Sometimes when I save some tex files (where the encoding has been set to `latin1`) and open them again, maybe in some other editors, all the special characters are lost and I need to manually retype them in.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
à è ì ò ù
\end{document}
```

In this example, the five accented letters would be replaced with other symbols, and I haven't found any way to recover the original version of the file.

I know that setting `utf8` in the `inputenc` package solves this problem when I create new files, but what about recovering older `latin1` files which, upon opening, are filled with corrupted characters?

Comment: Could you please provide a Minimum Working Example (MWE) that includes all packages dependencies and some text that produces you problem.

Comment: Tools such as `recode` or `iconv` can help.

Comment: Your question applies to text files in general; this suggests that it might be easiest to search for such general solutions, using keywords such as "repair", "encoding", "email", "fix", and "text".

Comment: @PeterJansson sure, I've updated my question

Comment: @LoverofStructure the problem is that this only happens to me with latex files

Comment: @PeterJansson first of all, why should I add "spanish"? And secondly, my question is more about how to recover a file when you already see corrupted characters, not how to correctly show accented letters, if this is what you meant with your comment.

Comment: Your editor should be aware of these encodings. BTW which editor you are using?

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: @HarishKumar Currently I am using TexWorks, but I used to use TexShop

Comment: @JLDiaz mostly Mac OS X, but I often use Linux for Latex too

Comment: In texmaker, at the lower (bottom) right end, there are three buttons. Middle one is for encoding. Click on the button and choose a proper encoding (say UTF-8). Will this solve your problem?

Comment: @user1301428 If you use OSX or Linux, you are lucky. Both include the program `iconv` which you can use from a terminal with the following syntax `iconv -f utf-8 -t latin1 < your-weird-file > new-fixed-file`. Alternatively, you can use an editor which properly shows `utf8`.

Comment: @HarishKumar if I click on the encoding nothing happens, am I missing something?

Comment: @user1301428 It is quite possible that the editor/IDE you are using for LaTeX is not Unicode-compatible or at least doesn't correctly save the codepage you need the characters in. You could check, by saving a few special characters in your file, saving, restarting, and reloading the file.

Comment: @JLDiaz Unfortunately with this method the weird symbols are simply replaced with other weird symbols...

Comment: @LoverofStructure this may indeed be the case, because I tend to have these problems with one editor only

Comment: @user1301428 In this case there are only two solutions: (1) Avoid non-ASCII characters in your source and use macros (such as `\\`a` for à) instead. (2) Upgrade the editor to the latest version (if that helps) or switch your editor/IDE. This is unfortunate; I have had this problem in the past as well.

Comment: The default encoding for TeX files created by TeXShop is neither Latin1 nor UTF-8, but Mac OS Roman.  So maybe your `iconv` command should be `inconv -f MAC -t UTF-8 < your-wierd-file > new-fixed-file`.  Also depending on the localization of your Mac, the files may be in other Mac encodings.  You can do `iconv --list` to see the list of encodings it can manage.

Comment: @AlanMunn Unfortunately this didn't work either... So I guess that sometimes it's not possible to solve encoding problems :)

Comment: You might also want to check out a `konwert` tool (is in Ubuntu repo, I don't know about Mac).  It is kind of a Swiss-army knife for converting files between encodings, imho better than `iconv`.  Among others, it can (try to) recognize the encoding.

Answer (score 2):

The "weird symbols" most probably are UTF-8 characters displayed in another encoding, and the file itself is fine. Use UTF-8 throughout (set your LOCALE properly in Unix/Linux is probably the most important measure). There are commands like recode that help changing the encoding, but be careful to use them right, they overwrite the original and can mess it up royally.